# PHP : Return JSON content instead of String from database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to return a **JSON** objet containing informations retrieved from my database.
Today, i only check that the username/password couple is correct and return a string "success".

The structure of tbl_user table is the following :

```
================================
============ tbl_user ==========
================================
- id
- username
- password
- name
- surname
- city
================================
================================
```

If the username/password couple exist in database, i would like to return a **JSON** object like that :

```
{
   username : ..,
   name : ..,
   surname : ..,
   city : ..
}
```

How can i do this ?

Here is my PHP code :

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="database";
$username_localhost ="myusername";
$password_localhost ="mypassword";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query_search = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
 if($rows == 0) { 
 echo "fail"; 
 }
 else  {
    echo "success"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Your query is insecure / vulnerable to injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First alter your select statement:

```
select field1, field2, ... from tbl_user where username = ....
```

then:

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec);

// you will get JSON data of all fields used in your selection
$jsonData = json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: @wawanopoulos, sorry mistake in code. Proper code is: $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec); (updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your results in an array, then encode it to JSON as following:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use php [json encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function for you output, like:

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```